# Node - Input function wait the entire script to run

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm very inexperienced in node.js.

I'm trying to use the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276364/4836556) as a simple user input system (i just need this to read a single line of text), but the script only wait for a input after the rest of the code gets executed (in the case, i can type only after the last console.log is shown). My code:

```
/**
 *  @file criaIconeEmoji
 *  @brief Gera os ícones do Windows a partir de uma pasta com emojis em .svg
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var process = require('process');

function prompt(question, callback) {
    var stdin = process.stdin,
        stdout = process.stdout;

    stdin.resume();
    stdout.write(question);

    stdin.once('data', function (data) {
        callback(data.toString().trim());
    });
}

var pasta_temporaria = __dirname + "/tmp";
var icones_base_pasta = __dirname + "/base_folder";
var icones_base_biblioteca = __dirname + "/base_library";
var pasta_origem = '';


prompt('Please enter the whole folder path containing the svg assets: ', function (input) {
    pasta_origem = input;
});

console.log('Teste');
console.log(pasta_origem);
```

Comment: What is your expected output? can you give examples,  I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You'll want to move those `console.log` statements inside the callback, in place of that assignment

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear; i will edit the question